# Flutter Version solving failed when adding RXDart

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I receive the following error after adding `RXdart`to my pubspec.yaml:

`Because no versions of cached_network_image match >2.5.1 <3.0.0 and cached_network_image 2.5.1 depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0, cached_network_image ^2.5.1 requires flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0.`

Packages use:

```
ev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
  dio: ^4.0.0
  enum_to_string: ^2.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
  image_cropper: ^1.4.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  material_floating_search_bar: ^0.3.3
  meta: ^1.3.0
  permission_handler: ^6.1.1
  rxdart: ^0.26.0
  timeago: ^3.0.2
  uuid: ^3.0.1
```

What exactly do the message mean? How can this be solved?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have this error right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm very knowledgeable about the topic. But I had a similar issue and couldn't find anything that solves it.
Nevertheless, it helped me -
remove the line `rxdart: ^0.26.0` from the `pubspec.yaml` file  and then in the terminal

```
flutter pub add rxdart
flutter pub upgrade rxdart
```

As far as I know after [these](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/pull/43) changes they fixed this issue and everything should work fine